# Swap "ul li" dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

I have my ul : li list with a span named as badge which contains the total number of unread messages. So i want to shuffle all the li items with the highest number on top of the list and lowest or none to the last. I tried many solutions but still can`t get it. Another point is the count gets update live so the list should also shuffle live. Here is the code that i tried till now.

My HTML Code

```
<li>
  <span class="badge" style="display:none" id="61_T">0</span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="badge" style="display:none" id="62_T">5</span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="badge" style="display:none" id="63_T">10</span>
</li>
<li>
  <span class="badge" style="display:none" id="64_T">0</span>
</li>
```

Here is my JS Code

```
var prev_index = 0;
var curr_index = 0;
var curr_val = 0;
var prev_val = 0;
var lists = $('#items li');

var msg_count = [];
$('#items li').each(function(){
 var current_index = $(this).index();
 var count =  $(this).find('.badge').text();
 msg_count.push([current_index,count]);
});

updateli();

function  updateli(){
  $.each(msg_count,function(key,value){
      var str = value.join('-');
      var sep = str.split('-');

      curr_index = sep[0];
      curr_val  = parseInt(sep[1]);
      if(curr_val > prev_val){
        $("#items    li:eq("+curr_index+")").siblings().eq(curr_index).after(lists.siblings(':eq('+prev_index+')'));
      }
       prev_index = curr_index;
       prev_val = curr_val;
    });
   }
```

What i did here is created an array with li index and unread count number. After than looped the array and used jQuery  function to swap the elements but nothing seems to work. Any help will really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: well firstly there's a stray `</p>` at the end of each `<span>` element

Comment: @Cauterite i forgot to remove that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sorts the list without using JQuery

```js
function sortItems(containerSelector, itemSelector, countSelector, asc) {
  let container = document.querySelector(containerSelector);
  let items = [].slice.call(container.querySelectorAll(itemSelector));
  items.sort(function(currItem, nextItem) {
    var currCountElement = currItem.querySelector(countSelector);
    var nextCountElement = nextItem.querySelector(countSelector);
    if(!currCountElement) return 1;
    if(!nextCountElement) return -1;
    var currCount = parseInt(currCountElement.textContent || -1);
    var nextCount = parseInt(nextCountElement.textContent || -1);
    var order = currCount - nextCount;
    return asc?-order:order;
  });
  
  items.forEach(function(item) { container.appendChild(item)});
}



// demo code
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.sortButton')).forEach(function(button) {
  button.addEventListener('click', function(e) { sortItems('.items', 'li', '.badge', this.classList.contains('-desc')) });
});
```

```html
<ul class="items">
  <li>
  2
   <span class="badge" style="display:none" id="61_T">2</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  5
    <span class="badge" style="display:none" id="62_T">5</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  10
    <span class="badge" style="display:none" id="63_T">10</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  1
    <span class="badge" style="display:none" id="63_T">1</span>
  </li>
  <li>
  0
    <span class="badge" style="display:none" id="64_T">0</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    none
    <span class="badge" style="display:none" id="64_T"></span>
  </li>
  <li>
    no badge
    
  </li>
</ul>

<button class="sortButton">asc</button>
<button class="sortButton -desc">desc</button>
```

Edit: made it a method

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. But there is an error it doesnt work when the value is 1.

Comment: I updated the snippet, its working with a value of 1

Comment: Add that snippet to your question with the html which is not working. I tried a value of `1` inside the badge and also no value.

Comment: It does`nt work when the difference between two badge is 1 and  by default when there is only one 1 count in all list.

Answer (score 0):

try the code below please.jquery return a array-like object so you can sort elements by `sort(..)` method,and then replace all the `li`.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="badge" id="61_T">0</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="badge" id="62_T">5</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="badge" id="63_T">10</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="badge" id="64_T">0</span>
    </li>
</ul>
<script>
    var badges = $('.badge').parent().sort(function (a, b) {
        return parseInt($(b).find('span').text()) - parseInt($(a).find('span').text());
    });    
   badges.closest('ul').empty().append(badges);
</script>
```